# Simulate animation with bitmap changes

Tags: c#, animation, bitmap

I have a bitmap of a keyboard layout that I have 'image mapped' into sections, so I can determine what 'key' has been clicked by mapping it to the overall bitmap.

Once the 'key' has been determined, I would like to shrink the area (by a few pixels) occupied by the key and paint a reduced sized image onto the bitmap to simulate a `keydown` action. When the key is released the original image area should be restored.

I need to do this in C# for NET 4.0, can anyone give me some pointers?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
//--- Private helper class.
private class ImageMap
{
  public ImageMap(System.Drawing.Rectangle areaTeclaNormal, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, string textString, System.Drawing.Rectangle areaTeclaPulsada)
  {
    AreaTeclaNormal = areaTeclaNormal;
    Key = key;
    TextString = textString;
    BitmapTeclaNormal = getBitmapFrom(MapaTecladoNormal, areaTeclaNormal);
    BitmapTeclaPulsada = getBitmapFrom(MapaTecladoPulsado, areaTeclaPulsada);
  }

  public System.Drawing.Rectangle AreaTeclaNormal { get; private set; }
  public System.Windows.Forms.Keys Key { get; private set; }
  public string TextString { get; private set; }
  public System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapTeclaNormal { get; private set; }
  public System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapTeclaPulsada { get; private set; }
  public bool? IsTeclaPulsada { get; set; }
  public static System.Drawing.Bitmap MapaTecladoNormal { get; set; }
  public static System.Drawing.Bitmap MapaTecladoPulsado { get; set; }

  private static System.Drawing.Bitmap getBitmapFrom(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmTecladoPulsado, System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle)
  {
    return bmTecladoPulsado.Clone(rectangle, bmTecladoPulsado.PixelFormat);
  }
}


//--- This is a class member to store the list of maps.
private readonly List<ImageMap> listaImageMaps = new List<ImageMap>();

//--- Inside my c'tor.
listaImageMaps.Add(new ImageMap(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(3, 187, 60, 60), System.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad1, "1", new System.Drawing.Rectangle(3, 174, 56, 56)));
listaImageMaps.Add(new ImageMap(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(64, 187, 60, 60), System.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad2, "2", new System.Drawing.Rectangle(60, 174, 56, 56)));
listaImageMaps.Add(new ImageMap(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(124, 187, 60, 60), System.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad3, "3", new System.Drawing.Rectangle(116, 174, 56, 56)));

//--- Eventa handlers
private void editImage_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
  ImageMap imageMap = listaImageMaps.Find(item => item.AreaTeclaNormal.IntersectsWith(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 1, 1)));
  if(imageMap != null)
  {
    imageMap.IsTeclaPulsada = true;
    editImage.Update();
  }
}

private void editImage_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
  ImageMap imageMap = listaImageMaps.Find(item => item.IsTeclaPulsada.HasValue && item.IsTeclaPulsada == true);
  if(imageMap != null)
  {
    imageMap.IsTeclaPulsada = false;
    editImage.Update();
  }
}

private void editImage_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
  ImageMap imageMap = listaImageMaps.Find(item => item.IsTeclaPulsada.HasValue);
  if(imageMap != null)
  {
    if(imageMap.IsTeclaPulsada == true)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageMap.BitmapTeclaPulsada, imageMap.AreaTeclaNormal.Left + 2, imageMap.AreaTeclaNormal.Top + 2, imageMap.BitmapTeclaPulsada.Width, imageMap.BitmapTeclaPulsada.Height);
    }
    else
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageMap.BitmapTeclaNormal, imageMap.AreaTeclaNormal.Left, imageMap.AreaTeclaNormal.Top, imageMap.BitmapTeclaNormal.Width, imageMap.BitmapTeclaNormal.Height);
      imageMap.IsTeclaPulsada = null;
    }
  }
}
```

The ImageMap helper class is used to define the different regions within the main bitmap, it defines the area occupied and the non-pressed key image and the pressed key image.

I use the nullable IsTeclaPulsada property to indicate if any painting is needed: True = paint the pressed key image, False = paint the normal key image and Null = requieres no processing.

I use the MouseDown and MouseUp events to trigger the process and the Paint event to paint the required key state regions.

The first event (MouseDown) paints the pressed image, but when the MouseUp has triggered the painting event does not paint the unpressed image straight away (it take several seconds!)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is not the place to just ask for pointers, this site answers specific problems.

Comment: however there are many tricks to achieve the keypress, but could you post how you render your bitmap?  let's try to go with your way.

Comment: look into `Graphics.DrawImage` It is available as a parameter in the `Paint` event and has a format which lets you define a target rectangle. If you make that a little smaller the image drawn will be smaller than the source rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution seems to be to use editImage.Refresh() instead of editImage.Update().